# Program for word reversal randomly skips out letters?

Tags: python

My program keeps randomly skipping out letters! For example, 'coolstory' becomes 'yrotsloc' and 'awesome' becomes 'mosewa'

Here is the code:

```
def reverse(text):
    length = len(text)
    reversed_text = []
    for i in range(0,length + 1):
        reversed_text += ['']
    original_list = []
    for l in text:
        original_list.append(l)
        new_place = length - (original_list.index(l))
        reversed_text[new_place] = l
    return "".join(reversed_text)
```

EDIT: Thanks for the answers everyone. I just rediscovered this forgotten account. I can assure you 6 years later I know how to properly reverse strings in a variety of different languages :)

Comment: This is a very convoluted way to reverse a string! `text[::-1]` would do the trick.

Comment: It is not so random. It is on the repeated letters... You are using index...

Comment: Why I run this, it gives me `'yrtsloc'`, not `yrotsloc`. Is your description wrong, or is this not your actual code?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This happens when you have duplicate letters because

```
original_list.index(l)
```

will always return the same value for the same `l`. So `new_place` will be the same for two of the same letters at different locations.

One common way to reverse strings in Python is with slicing:

```
>>> s = "hello"
>>> s[::-1]
'olleh'
```

You can also use [`reversed()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#reversed), but that returns a `reversed object` (not a string). This is a better option if you want to iterate over a string in reverse order:

```
>>> for c in reversed(s):
...     print c
... 
o
l
l
e
h
```

Comment: This certainly looks like it _should_ be the error but I cannot see how it explains the examples given in the question?

Comment: @JackAidley, `reversed_text[new_place] = l` sets an existing position with the same char

Comment: @JackAidley: Given this explanation, it should produce `yrtsloc`, not `yrotsloc`. And if you run the code… it produces `yrtsloc`. So either the examples given in the question are wrong, or the code isn't the OP's actual code. Either way, arshaji has explained what's wrong with the code the OP gave us…

Answer (score 3):

Try

```
def reverse(text):
    return text[::-1]
```